# Adding radio stations to Banshee from m3u files

Tags: banshee, internet-radio

So I can get Banshee to play WGBH 995 Classical New England (http://www.wgbh.org/995/) by downloading the m3u file (http://streams.wgbh.org/streamb/classical.m3u) and telling Firefox to open the file in Banshee.  But I want to save the radio station in my library.

The file classical.m3u has the following contents:

```
#EXTM3U
http://streams.wgbh.org:8006/
```

So I bring up the "Add new radio station" dialog box and put http://streams.wgbh.org:8006/ in for the "Stream URL:".  When I double click the resulting entry in the Radio Station list, Banshee goes to "Contacting..." and then back to "Idle."  What gives?

I'm using Banshee 2.2.1, and am behind a proxy server, but it works when it opens the m3u file, so it must be configured to use the proxy.

Comment: I just tried adding the station in the way you described and it worked perfectly. Might just have been a temporary server error.

Comment: Just tried again and still not working.  What version of Banshee did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any radio station you know the URL of by opening Banshee *Radio* context menu to select *Add Station*. This will open the following window:

[image]

Select the Genre, the station name and give in the full *Stream URL*,in your case:

```
http://streams.wgbh.org/streamb/classical.m3u
```

This will add the station with the name you chose to the radios available. Select the station, then *Play*. Adding the stream provider address:port may not work in your network environment.